# Overlay views but propagate input down to lowest z-index

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode11

Using SwiftUI, I want to create a View where the User can select a region on a map. For this, I want to use the MapKit and draw a slightly opaque, red circle above which indicates the current region. Depending on the zoom level, the region becomes bigger or smaller.

I already have the following code (MapView is taken from this cheat sheet https://github.com/SimpleBoilerplates/SwiftUI-Cheat-Sheet#navigation):

```
import MapKit

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        MKMapView(frame: .zero)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: 34.011286,
            longitude: -116.166868
        )
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 2.0, longitudeDelta: 2.0)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
        view.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}

struct LocationSelectionView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MapView()
            .overlay(
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.init(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, opacity: 0.3))
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            )
    }
}
```

Which results in the following:
[image]

Now, the **problem** is, that scrolling around the map does not work anymore if I am within the red circle because the input is directed to the circle but not propagated down to the actual map. It is still possible to scroll the map outside of the circle.

How can I pass the users gestures down to the MapView so that the circle is just an actual, visual overlay without any functionality?

Answer (score 2):

### - Disable Tap:

Set `.allowsHitTesting(false)` on the `Circle`

### - Disable Pan:

Not possible in SwiftUI (yet).

Comment: Thanks but this did not work. I also tried it with ZStack instead of .overlay().

Comment: It should be the latest version. 11.0 (11A420a) it says. I applied this function to the circle but when running the simulator and just dragging the mouse around on the circle, the map behind it does not move.